# Docker in WSL - Can't connect to SQL server on 'localhost' but with '127.0.0.1' SQL Server 2017-latest

Tags: sql-server, docker, powershell, docker-compose

Trying to spin up an mssql server with a docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    container_name: sqlserver
    user: root
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_USERNAME: sa
      SA_PASSWORD: Dev1234!
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/data2:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./volumes/backup:/var/opt/mssql/Backup
```

The server is up and running successfully, But when tried to connect with powershell script code:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=localhost,1433;User ID=sa;Password=Dev1234!;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$connection.Open();
```

It throws error like:

```
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name
is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The
remote computer refused the network connection.)"
```

That is, it fails when trying to connect with **'localhost'** as host, it is successfully connecting when **"127.0.0.1"** is specified as host.

The same happens when I tried to connect with SQL server management studio.
[image]

My docker engine is running in wsl, an ubuntu distro specifically. There is MySQL and different other servers already spun up which I can access with localhost.

Is there anything I need to specify in docker-compose to make this work? When checking documentation, there are no params aligned to it as I see.

Comment: So if you `ping localhost` or `tracert localhost` what address does it resolve to? Since you're able to connect using `127.0.0.1` I'm expecting that `localhost` resolves to the IPv6 address `::1` or something other than `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning 'localhost' is resolving to '127.0.01' when tried to ping, what makes it more confusing is I can connect to MySQL and different other services by specifying 'localhost' itself.

Comment: Just to confirm... you are running the PowerShell script on the Docker host machine, not inside another Docker container?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Host machine only.

Comment: Also to confirm... you've checked the container's log output to confirm that it's **not** returning any error messages? If you check the documentation for [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server), for example, it expects the sa password to be supplied via `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` as opposed to `SA_PASSWORD`. And there's no `SA_USERNAME` variable for configuration (it won't error, but it doesn't do anything either).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning In that case, it must show an error when connecting with 127.0.0.1 also right? btw there are no logs thrown in container output, I double-checked it.

Comment: The log files are in the SQL Server.  Use SQL Server Management Studio an in the explorer check the log files under Management.  Also check the credentials on the login windows in SSMS and try a test query.  If the login says Windows Credentials user and password will not work.  The log files will show the user that tried to login and the group.  The user and group should be the same when you login using SSMS.

Comment: @jdweng The SQL server is connecting successfully with UDL files in windows without any issues.

Comment: What is your connection string?  Connection string should be the same in PS as in UDL files.  In windows you may be running as Admin, but not in PS.  You may need to start PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.   Make sure the log files login account and group are the same in UDL as in PS.

Comment: @jdweng I created just a dummy UDL file to log in with the windows UI(by double-clicking it). I tried PS as an administrator as well, but no luck :(

Comment: The connection string is not the same in the UDL and the PS.  Check the log files in SSMS and compare the login (user account and group) when running the UDL and PS.  They must be different or there is no entry which means the Server/Instance is different.  The Server/Instance is on the login window of SSMS.  Also on login is the Credentials (either Window or SQL).  If window than connection string musty contain Integrate Security = True which means Windows Credential.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The workaround to "solve" is disable IPV6 on all adapters.